# How to find the page is currently in the list or not?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, navigation, widget

I have a List of Pages. The list type is `widget`. when I tried to find if there is any element match with the `HomePage` it always return false.

**This is my code:**

```
List<Widget> pages = [Home(), SecondPage(), ThirdPage(),SizedBox()]
```

when I check with the condition `pages.contains(Home())` it gives false.

how do I find if the `HomePage` is currently present in the list or not.So that I can navigate to the correct previous page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with runtimeType.

`pages.map((e) -> e.runtimeType).contains(Home().runtimeType)`

Reason:
Objects in flutter are not equal (except primitive data types and String) by default. Hence 2 objects of Home() is not equals. `contains` works with equality. runtimeType of class will be string so contains will work.

Comment: This one is very clean. I never thought that I would use the `runtimeType ` in this way.Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

This helps you.

```dart
bool hasHome = pages.any((page) => page is Home);
```

[Iterable any method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/any.html)

Comment: this one didn't work.Thanks by the way

Comment: This answer is improves what I suggested. I tired it https://dartpad.dev and it worked well.

Comment: It will work in this method. It is an alternative to Rahul's answer, as Rahul said.